# Debian Buster can't find package

Tags: debian, debian-buster

I am using a debian buster based docker image.  I want to install this package:

https://packages.debian.org/buster/php-memcache

But when I try it says package not found:

```
# apt install php-memcache
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php-memcache is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php-memcache' has no installation candidate
```

I appear to have the right repository:

```
#grep ^[^#] /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
```

Why is this package not available?

Comment: Did you run `apt update`? Usually the local package cache is empty in container images.

Comment: yes, I ran apt update

Comment: I have the same issue. Any suggestions ?